# fit_transform data before running algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

> The preprocessing module further provides a utility class
>   StandardScaler that implements the Transformer API to compute the mean
>   and standard deviation on a training set so as to be able to later
>   reapply the same transformation on the testing set.
>   http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.fit_transform

When transforming the dataset you run an algorithm on, how do you link the results back to the original dataset?

E.g.

```
data = [[0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1]]
print(data); 
-->[[0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1]]
myData = StandardScaler().fit_transform(data)
print(myData);
-->[[-1. -1.]
   [-1. -1.]
   [ 1.  1.]
   [ 1.  1.]]
```

When running an algorithm on myData (unsupervised), how can you interpret results on that dataset when it's changed before running? E.g. when you run a clustering algorithm on myData, you are not clustering the original data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the [`inverse_transform`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.inverse_transform) to get back to the original data:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np

data = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]

scaler = StandardScaler()

myData = scaler.fit_transform(data)

restored = scaler.inverse_transform(myData)

assert np.allclose(restored, data)  # check we got the original data back
```

Note how an instance of `StandardScaler` is stored in a variable for later use. After fitting, this instance contains all the information required to repeat or undo the transformation.

Now, if you performed clustering on `myData` you can pass the cluster prototypes (centers, or whatever you get from the clustering algorithm) to `scaler.inverse_transform` to get the clusters in the original data space.